# How to pass a function with arguments and stop_condition in jthread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++20

I am trying to do something like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

void doWork(char a, std::stop_token st = {}) {
    while (!st.stop_requested()) {
        std::cout << a << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    std::jthread t1{doWork, 'A'}, // error
                 t2{doWork, 'B'}; // error
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50));
}
```

But it won't compile on gcc trunk with `-std=c++2a`:

```
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20200219/include/c++/10.0.1/thread:537:20: error: static assertion failed: std::thread arguments must be invocable after conversion to rvalues

  537 |      static_assert(is_invocable_v<decay_t<_Callable>,

      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  538 |       decay_t<_Args>...>,

      |       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Is it even possible to do something like this?

I assumed that it should be possible, because I've seen a similar example with lambda ([here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0660r10.pdf)):

```
//...
std::jthread t([&ready, &readyMutex, &readyCV] (std::stop_token st) {
    while (!stoken.stop_requested()) {
        //...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are almost correct in your implementation. The [constraint on the invokable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread/jthread) is that it accepts a `std::stop_token` as a *first* argument. So switching the order in the declaration of `doWork` will sort it out.

```
void doWork(std::stop_token st, char a) {
    while (!st.stop_requested()) {
        std::cout << a << '\n';
    }
}
```

The token comes from the library implementation, so its construction is not meant to worry you anyway.